# Zend RestController xml response > multiple rows

Tags: php, zend-framework

Iam using Zend RestController to output student data (from database) in xml format. Iam assigning the row data from controller, to the view elements (column by column).

Like this:

```
$this->view->name = $name;
$this->view->desc = $desc;
```

But, what if have to show data of multiple rows?

I have the following code in my index.xml.phtml, which gives only 1 row data:

```
<pre>
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$root_element = $doc->createElement("Students");
$doc->appendChild($root_element);

$nameElement = $doc->createElement("student");
$nameElement->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($this->name));
$root_element->appendChild($nameElement);

print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

How can i loop through the result set array and output it as xml (multiple rows) ?

Comment: Why don't you use $name array in for loop to appendChild.

Comment: Because i want name from each row of database in a separate xml root tree, not all names under one xml tag, like i want: name, description fields of 1 row under one xml root tag (Student), another set of name and description under another xml root tag, and so on, and finally all these individual student tags must be under the "Students" root tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine, i got the solution by looping the resultset using foreach.

For each row of my resultset, i appended the column data to a child element (Ex: "Name") and then appended this child element to a root element (Student).

```
{ // using foreach loop
$nameElement = $doc->createElement("Name");
$nameElement->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($this->name)); // add Name to "Student"
$root_element->appendChild($nameElement);
}
```

So finally the super root element (Students) contains the root elements as childs. I mean, the "Students" contain all "Student" data.